# Java difference between two times

Tags: java, time

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Calculating the Difference Between Two Java Date Instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555262/calculating-the-difference-between-two-java-date-instances)

time1: 17:05 time2: 17:08

I'd like to get the difference in seconds.

Comment: Hopefully, internet does not yet exist in the timespace continuum. Elsewhere, I guess copy/pasting question title in google/bing/duckduckgo would bring you an anwser.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
 long diffInMillis =    newerDate.getTime() - olderDate.getTime()
```

**Must See**

- [API doc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html)

Comment: You can also use:

`long diffInMillis =    newerDate.getTimeInMillis() - olderDate.getTimeInMillis()`

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Date Class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Date.html)

```
long diffInSec =    (newerDate.getTime() - olderDate.getTime())/1000;
```