# How to set in JAVA calendar value to tommorow day at 8 A.M

Tags: java

I have date time field. How to set to value to 8 A.M (if time value is between 16:00-00:00) and in the same time to set it for tomorrow date? I need to increase it with value for one day and set it to 8 A.M

I tried

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(); 
calendar.setTime(mydate); 
calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);

date= calendar.getTime()
```

but I do not know how to check if mydate is in interval between 16:00 and 00:00 because than I must do the addition. Also do not know hot to set time value for static 8 A.M value

Please help,
thank you

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Comment: @jajaaaa updated my answer.have a look.

Comment: thank you. Just how to determine if date is in interval between 16:00 and 00:00? thank you

Comment: Read the documentation, you'll learn 10x more.

Comment: where can I found documentaion about if some time value from date time field is in some interval? thank you

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at `Calendar` class.Set the Date to it and add days and time,and get back the time again.

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(); 
calendar.setTime(yourdate); 
calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8);;  
date= calendar.getTime();
```

You can use [**HOUR_OF_DAY**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#HOUR_OF_DAY) for specific hour.

Comment: calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR, 1); this is problematic part on example if I have date 5 may 17:00 I want to set it to 6 may to 8 A.M I am not doing any addition of hours I am always setting it to ONE THE SAME value - 8 A.M. And mydate filed is always different values

Comment: OK this is what I wanted. I am just missing some if clause to check if my dateField is between 16:00 and 00:00 if this is true than I am doing your code. Else I am not doing anything on my field. How to do this check on my field? tHANK YOU

Comment: I upvoted and I will mark it as an answer but do you know how to determine if time of my date field is between interval 16:00-00:00? Or you can not help me with this?

Comment: @jajaaaa This might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4927856/how-to-calculate-time-difference-in-java

Comment: Sorry but I do not need difference. I just need something like this (if myDate is between 16:00 and 00:00) then ....your code... do not need any other calculations

Comment: can you help with this one? regards

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4569476/java-difference-between-two-times

Comment: This is the best you can get http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-calculate-date-time-difference-in-java/

Answer (score 0):

try the solution from this [How to add one day to a date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005523/how-to-add-one-day-to-a-date)

to add one day. Then just set the time to what you want.

Comment: I know how to set date increase it with one value but how to set it to static value to time 8 A.M

Comment: Maybe late, just if someone else wants to know the difference is what needs to be used in cal.settime...